# python match statement - invalid syntax when using json_dumps

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, match, raspberry-pi4

I would like to replace an if statement in python with a match statement, however I get an invalid syntax error.

**Modified code (replaced if statement with match):
**

```
# Callback when the subscribed topic receives a message
def on_message_received(topic, payload, dup, qos, retain, **kwargs):
    print("Received message from topic '{}': {}".format(topic, payload))
    global received_count
    received_count += 1

    m_decode=str(payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
    print("data Received type",type(m_decode))
    print("data Received",m_decode)
    print("Converting from Json to Object")
    m_in=json.loads(m_decode) #decode json data
    print(type(m_in))
    print("action = ",m_in["action"])

    match m_in["action"]:
       case "left":
         panLeftClick()
       case "right":
         panRightClick()
       case "up":
         tiltUpClick()
       case "down":
         tiltDownClick()
       case _:
         print( "action not found: ", m_in["action"]
```

**Output:**

File "/home/pi/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/samples/rs-iot-cam.py", line 210
match m_in["action"]:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

My understanding is that I should be able to use match statements with a dictionary object but I'm not sure of the correct syntax. Can anyone assist?

**Environment:
**
python --version
Python 3.9.2

uname -a
Linux raspberrypi4 5.15.76-v7l+ #1597 SMP Fri Nov 4 12:14:58 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux

```
**Original code (worked ok):
**

# Callback when the subscribed topic receives a message
def on_message_received(topic, payload, dup, qos, retain, **kwargs):
    print("Received message from topic '{}': {}".format(topic, payload))
    global received_count
    received_count += 1

    m_decode=str(payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
    print("data Received type",type(m_decode))
    print("data Received",m_decode)
    print("Converting from Json to Object")
    m_in=json.loads(m_decode) #decode json data
    print(type(m_in))
    print("action = ",m_in["action"])


###
    if m_in["action"]  ==  'left':
        panLeftClick()
    elif m_in["action"] ==  'right': 
        panRightClick()
    elif m_in["action"]  ==  'up': 
        tiltUpClick()
    elif m_in["action"]  ==  'down': 
        tiltDownClick()
```

```
**Publish MQTT message from AWS IoT console:
**
[AWS Console MQTT Publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkjqg.png)


**Output:
**
Received message from topic 'rs-iot-cam': b'{\n  "action": "left"\n}'
data Received type <class 'str'>
data Received {
  "action": "left"
}
Converting from Json to Object
<class 'dict'>
action =  left
panLeftClick
Pan Left to -10


Received message from topic 'rs-iot-cam': b'{\n  "action": "up"\n}'
data Received type <class 'str'>
data Received {
  "action": "up"
}
Converting from Json to Object
<class 'dict'>
action =  up
tiltUpClick
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python3.9. `match` statement was added in Python3.10.

Use Python3.10 to use `match` statement.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html